# How to enable Global HTTP Proxy on a non-supervised iPhone?

Tags: iphone, proxy, ios6

Is there a way to enable the new "Global HTTP Proxy" on a non-supervised iPhone running iOS 6?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recall it correcly, it's only possoble via WiFi: Go to the Settings app, tap Wi-Fi, find the network you are connected to and then tap the blue disclosure arrow to configure the network. Scroll down to the HTTP Proxy setting, tap Manual.